# Why should I write lifetime annotation in function that doesn't have any parameters, rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-cargo

Why should I write lifetime annotation in this function, although it does not take any parameter:

```
fn book<'a>() -> &'a i32 {
    &10
}
```

Why this not compile:

```
fn book() -> &i32 {
    &10
}
```

Comment: A `fn<'a>() -> &'a T` is about equivalent to a `fn() -> &'static T`, because the caller can choose any `'a`, and because shared references are covariant in relation to their lifetime, `'static` is a "superset" of all other references. So if you add `&'static i32` to the second example it does compile

Comment: thank you, but how caller can choose any `'a`, is there an example?

Comment: They can just call it as `book::<'some_lifetime>()` with `'some_lifetime` being e.g. a generic parameter on their own function.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, your function does not match to any of the three [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html):

> - Each elided lifetime in the parameters becomes a distinct lifetime parameter.
> - If there is exactly one lifetime used in the parameters (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.
> - If the receiver has type &Self or &mut Self, then the lifetime of that reference to Self is assigned to all elided output lifetime parameters.

therefore you have to annotate it.

As for examples choosing the lifetime:

```rust
// implicitly the lifetime is long enough so that `b` is valid in it's context
let b = book();
// or explicitly (passing the choice to the next caller):
fn return_book<'a>() -> &'a i32 {
    book<'a>()
}
```